# BotFramework DateTimePrompt locale not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, botframework, web-chat

I am using bitframework 4 on nodejs. I cant get the DateTimePrompt to use locale 'en-GB' which has date format dd/mm (not mm/dd) I set locale in 3 places none worked:

```js
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, (context) => {
      context.activity.locale = 'en-GB';
      return myChatBot.run(context);
    };
```

```js
    this.addDialog(new DateTimePrompt('startDatePrompt', undefined, 'en-GB'));
```

and in the webchat frame:

```js
    window.WebChat.renderWebChat(
      {
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token: token }),
        locale: 'en-GB',
        webSpeechPonyfillFactory
      },
      document.getElementById('webchat')
    );
```

I just want the date parser to parse as dd/mm not mm/dd any thoughts?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. I can tell you that the activity locale takes precedence over the prompt locale, but you seem to be setting the activity locale correctly in your Web Chat implementation. Can you give us an example of an utterance that gets recognized incorrectly? Also, can you check to make sure your incoming activities have the correct locale by doing something like `console.log(context.activity.locale);`?

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: @Armin, not the answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Create a customer prompt with regex expression. This will give you the flexibility you need.

In your constructor use a TextPrompt and pass the promptvalidator

```
this.addDialog(new TextPrompt(DATE_PROMPT, this.datePromptValidator));
```

In the dialogstep with the prompt.

```
    async dateStep(stepContext) {
        await helper.say(stepContext, 'Please enter a date');
        const promptOptions = { retryPrompt: 'This is not a valid date. Please use mm/dd' };
        return await stepContext.prompt(WHEN_PROMPT, promptOptions);
    }
```

Since the promptvalidator will use turnState (works for me) to share the result with the dialogstep, we check for this in the next dialogStep

```
    async stepafterDateStep(stepContext) {
        stepContext.values.date = stepContext.context.turnState.match;
    }
```

And the promptvalidator uses a regular expression to check for the right format. These regex expression tend to become complex. This one checks for dd/mm/yyyy. There are libraries available like https://regexlib.com/

```
    async datePromptValidator(promptContext) {
               const regex = new RegExp(/(((0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])([-./])(0[13578]|10|12)([-./])(\d{4}))|(([0][1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)([-./])(0[469]|11)([-./])(\d{4}))|((0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])([-./])(02)([-./])(\d{4}))|((29)(\.|-|\/)(02)([-./])([02468][048]00))|((29)([-./])(02)([-./])([13579][26]00))|((29)([-./])(02)([-./])([0-9][0-9][0][48]))|((29)([-./])(02)([-./])([0-9][0-9][2468][048]))|((29)([-./])(02)([-./])([0-9][0-9][13579][26])))/);

        var matches = promptContext.recognized.value.match(regex);
        if (matches) {
            promptContext.context.turnState.match = matches[0];
            return true;
        } else { return false; };
    }
```